# Number of levels for ordinal DV, variance, and statistical significance

Tags: statistical-significance, variance, statistical-power, ordinal-data, scales

I am interested in how closely a person places themselves to a certain situation in the responses they give. The responses are coded, and I create a score, with the lowest value indicating the person distancing themselves from the situation as much as they can and the highest value indicating that they place themselves as closely as they can.

Now the score is usually created in a certain way, ranging from 0 to 3. I created a second score based on the idea that perhaps differences between groups become visible only when we look at smaller steps in terms of how closely they place themselves in regard to that situation (score from 0 to 5).

My questions are:

- My feeling is that, whilst becoming more sensitive to differences, adding more levels to the DV also makes it more difficult to obtain statistically significant results. Somehow I attribute this to there being more categories, potentially also with few cases in them, which in my mind somehow reduces power. I would very much appreciate if somebody could explain to me whether this feeling is correct and explain why (in plain English rather than with mathematical forumlae if possible).
- Am I correct in assuming that a more fine-grained scale has the potential to detect more variance if it exists? And is there a way of quantifying the variance in the scale and comparing it between the two scales for an ordinal measure?

Comment: Why the feeling? You could test this yourself  by some simple simulations!

Comment: Why do you feel that *increasing* the precision with which you represent your data would *decrease* power?  That's counterintuitive. It sounds like you are contemplating some particular kind of statistical analysis that potentially is inappropriate.  Providing a clearer more concrete description of what you're doing would help us understand your question.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I'd love to do that but unfortunately don't have the skills

Comment: @whuber typically it is found that the vast majority of participants have high scores, i.e. there are heavily skewed distributions. My reasoning, from a content point of view, is that differences may lie in the smaller steps that could potentially be detected by using a more nuanced scale. The data is ordinal scaled. My experience with such data so far has been that if there are more categories but few cases in individual categories, differences are less likely to reach significance. But coming to think of it that's probably not bc of a power-related reason.. not sure why it is though.

Comment: "Reach significance" depends on what statistical procedure you use.  It's really a separate issue from how you represent the data.

Comment: @whuber thank you for your response. What I meant is if I use the exact same nonparametric test, results may turn out statistically significant with one measure but not the other. So it would be the same procedure with different outcome variables.

Comment: Again, my point is that it depends on the test: that's the issue you might consider focusing on.  As an example, the loss of degrees of freedom incurred by modeling each category separately often can be avoided with a more parsimonious model, such as a spline.  This is an issue separate from using a parametric or non-parametric procedure.

Comment: @whuber many thanks for clarifying this. I'm using Mann-Whitney U-tests as the data is ordinal in nature, heavily skewed, and violates other assumptions as well